# Plain installation vs Virtual machines - what is better for multicore?

Tags: multithreading, hyperthreading

We've currently bought a new server, with 64 GB of RAM and 8 cores with hyperthreading support. We are going to build a system using:

- nginx.
- apache.
- mysql.
- php

So, the question is about performance: How to use the cores most effectively?

Is it better to install a single operation system and tune the individual applications or create several virtual machines, and let each machine exploit it's ressources (e.g. core)?

Answer (score 2):

The advantages of using virtual machines is not so much in increased performance per se. The main idea is that in many cases you want system isolation, i.e., you don't want one system to interfere with the other. This plays a major role in cloud computing, since a provider might host appliances for many different customers and of course these need to be securely separated. If a bare metal approach is used, in which case each customer has its own machine, the systems are likely not fully utilized. Hosting many VMs on a single physical machine increases utilization while still offering a secure environment.

However, hosting VMs comes with its own [overhead](https://serverfault.com/a/135491/269099). Software might not run as efficient on the virtualized hardware, the virtual machines must be managed from the host and there is a lot of redundancy between the VMs. This introduces a penalty on performance, rather than a bonus.

In your case you might want to run each service in a separate virtual machine for security or maintenance reasons. If one of your services is compromised, others might not be affected. Also, it's easy to make snapshots of each VMs, which eases maintenance, among other things. I would not bet on improved performance though.

An alternative to VMs is [operating-system-level-virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization) such as container technology, recently popularized on Linux by [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). They allow for multiple isolated user space instances, eliminating the need to run multiple full-blown operating systems, thus significantly reducing the performance penalty while providing many of the advantages of VMs. Docker containers are easy to roll out and also support snapshots.

Comment: This is appropriate if considering full virtualization only. There are virtualization mechanisms such as containers (OpenVZ and LXC) which offer nearly-native performance.

Comment: I agree. I've added Docker as an example.

Comment: Just saw your edit as I was commenting :-) .

Answer (score 0):

> So, the question is about performance - how to use the cores most effectively?

If you have nothing else on this box running, I would go with a plain and simple install - although I am no friend of putting all on one box. 
There is near to nothing comparable to running "native". As @Benjamin B. said: Docker is a virtualization level with very low overhead. But unless you have reasons to virtualize, I wouldn't do it with such a simple setup. It adds at least an extra organziational overhead to your project.

> Is it better to create a single operation system and tune the components I described effectively or create several virtual machines, and let each machine exploit it's core?

Why should this be anything better? Say, you are running Ubuntu on your box and install VMs with Ubuntu: why should a Guest-Ubuntu behave different than as an ordinary install?

Operating systems are built to effectively manage ressources, so running everything on a plain install should do the trick.

Virtualization is interesting if you plan to easily spin up and down instances / services; or if you need more finegrained levels of isolation.

But, since it is your only box, you are fine with a plain install.

OT: 
Why using apache and nginx?